# How can I filter a file by a List to retrieve every occurrence of each list element

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I wanted to parse a list of keywords through the filter to be able to retrieve each instance of the all the keywords in the list from the source file

I've tried using filter which works with hardcoded definition (e.g. "def", "if") but I wanted to make it work with the list, meaning I wouldn't have to hardcode each keyword.

```
val list = List("def, if, else")

val source = Source.fromFile("../file.scala").getLines.toList
val keywords = source filter (_.contains(???))
```

.contains(List) just gives me an empty list

Comment: `val keywords = source.filter(line => list.exists(word => line.contains(word)))`

Comment: still prints an empty list, doesn't seem to work

Comment: The proposed solution works, but take a look at your list definition, it contains only a single string. Thus the full string "def, if, else" had to be contained in one of the lines for the filtering to not return empty. Define instead ``` val list = List("def", "if", "else") ```

Comment: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ thank you @awagen